# How to filter out flagged emails from a specific account in Outlook 2010's task list

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

I have two Exchange Accounts in my Outlook. In the standard email-view, on the right you see a list of tasks for Today, Next Month, etc.

Currently, this list displays all flagged mails of both email-accounts.

Is there a way to only show those flagged emails which belong to one email-account?

Answer (score 3):

To get my results, I left the standard filters there (Completed Date & Flag Completed Date = does not exist) and added All Mails Fields > Changed by > my email address/partial of name.

Seems to be showing me correctly. Buzz if this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

This task list on the right is called **Outlook To-Do Bar**. You can try to right-click it, select **View Settings** there, after that click **Filter** button.

In the **Filter** dialog window go to **Advanced** tab, click **Field** button, select **All Mail Fields** > **E-mail Account** in the menu.

Type part of the required account's name in the **Value** text box and click **Add to List** button below.

Click **OK**, then **OK** again. You'd now set up filtered view for your tasks in the Outlook To-Do Bar.

Comment: What do you do when this doesn't work?  For me it either hides *all* items (including from the account you are supposed to be viewing) or it shows completed items from all accounts, contrary to the existing criteria that hide completed items!

Answer (score 1):

In the Outlook To-Do bar, click on Arrange By then choose View Settings.

Click on the Filter button.

In the Advanced tab, add a new filter: [Changed by] [is (exactly)] [Email account you want shown]. Click Add to list when done.

The other two default entries (date completed- does not exist, and flag completed date- does not exist) can be left as-is.

Answer (score 1):

I followed this and it worked for me

This task list on the right is called **Outlook To-Do Bar**. You can try to **right-click it**, select **View Settings** there, after that click **Filter button**.

In the Filter dialog window go to **Advanced tab**, **Field**, Type **"In Folder"**, **Condition:** Contains, **Value:** Inbox

I had to mess with it a little in the Fields drop down I searched through the "All Mail Fields" tab and just went through to see which one worked best "In Folder" just seemed like the right fit then in "Contains" you just put the name of the folder :)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is selecting a different field in the Advanced settings as mentioned in the solution above - Organizer [contains] [part of your email address].

Comment: This is same as the other (older) answer

Answer (score 0):

**Outlook 2010**:

- Go to `View setting for the To-Do Bar`
- `Filter->More Choices`
- `Select Items Flagged by me`

`Apply` filter.

Then go to `Account Settings` and remove the account you were trying to filter out, then add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the above did work correctly for me, I post my solution here. I used the following SQL query

```
(
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062003-0000-0000-C000000000000046}/811c000b" <> 1
  AND (
       "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3ffa001f" = 'john.doe@mail.tld'
    OR "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3ffa001f" = 'John Doe'
  )
)
```

The first query tells that you only want to show tasks not set to finished. The second part of the query is the **Changed by** filter mentioned in the postings above. But neither email nor name showed me all results, I had to use a `OR` statement to get all entries changed by my name (John Doe) or by my email (john.doe@mail.tld).